# How to allow unsafe-eval and Remote Script - CSP Content Security Policy

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

"GOOGLE EXTENSION WEB APP"

Drives me nuts.

I can't manage to have unsafe-eval and remote script both working.

I can have unsafe eval but the remove script doesn't work. And vice verso.

What failed:

Eval and Remote

`"content_security_policy": "script-src  https://connect.facebook.net 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' "`

What works:

Only Remote

`"content_security_policy": "script-src  'self'  https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self' "`

Only Eval

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' "`

How to have both ?

Comment: What does "failed" mean? Do you see an error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just merge the directive values:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'
```